# Property on the derivative of a wedge product of two n-forms

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following property of $n$-forms. 
When $w_1$ is a $n_1$-form on $M$, $w_2$ a $n_2$-form also on $M$, and $d$ denotes the exterior derivative
$$\require{cancel}
d(w_1\wedge w_2)=dw_1\wedge w_2+(-1)^{\mathrm{deg} w_1}w_1\wedge dw_2$$
($\mathrm{deg}w_1$ denotes the degree of the permutation in the entries corresponding to $w_1$).

Having that
\begin{eqnarray*}
dw(X_1,\cdots,X_{n+1})&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+1}X_i(w(X_1,\cdots\cancel{X_i},\cdots X_{n+1}))\\
&&+\sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j}w([X_i,X_j],X_1,\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,\cancel{X_j},\cdots,X_{n+1})\end{eqnarray*}
and
$$w_1\wedge w_2=\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!}\sum_P(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(P)}(w_1\otimes w_2)^P$$
I've managed to develop the summations, and, based in the terms I got for the $1$-form $1$-form case, I think I know how the terms must rearrange to pass from one side to the other, however I couldn't explicitly write the sumations. What I have in that point lead me to
\begin{eqnarray*}
d&&(w_1\wedge w_2)(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})=
\\
&&
=\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!}\sum_P(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(P)}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1+1}(-1)^{i+1}X_i[w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,X_{n_1+1})w_2^P(X_{n_1+2},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})]
\right .
\\
&&
+\sum_{i=n_1+2}^{n_1+n_2+1}(-1)^{i+1}X_i[w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1})w_2^P(X_{n_1+2},\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})]
\\
&&
+\sum_{j=1}^{n_1\neq1}\sum_{i=1}^j(-1)^{i+j}w_1([X_i,X_j],X_1,\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,\cancel{X_j},\cdots,X_{n_1})w_2(X_{P(n_1+2)},\cdots,X_{P(n_1+n_1+1)})
\\
&&
\left .
+\sum_{j=n_1}^{n_1+n_2+1}\sum_{i=n_1}^j(-1)^{i+1}w_1(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1})w_2([X_i,X_j],X_{n_1+1},\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,\cancel{X_j},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})\right\}
\\
&&
=\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!}\sum_P(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(P)}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+1}X_i(w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,X_{n_1+1}))w_2^P(X_{n_1+2},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})
\right .
\\
&&
+\sum_{i=1}^{n_1+1}(-1)^{i+1}w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,X_{n_1+1})X_i(w_2^P(X_{n_1+2},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1}))
\\
&&
\left .
+\sum_{j=1}^{n_1+1}\sum_{i=1}^j(-1)^{i+j}w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,X_{n_1+1})w_2^P(X_{n_1+2},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})\right\}
\\
&&
+\frac{1}{n_1!n_2!}\sum_P(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(P)}\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{n_2+1}(-1)^{k+1+n_1}X_i(w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1}))w_2^P(X_{n_1+1},\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})
\right .
\\
&&
+\sum_{k=1}^{n_2+1}(-1)^{k+n_1+1}w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1})(X_i(w_2^P(X_{n_1+1},\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1}))
\\
&&
\left .
+\sum_{k=1}^{n_1+1}\sum_{i<k+n_1}(-1)^{k+n_1+i}w_1^P(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1})w_2^p([X_i,X_k],X_{n_1+1},\cdots,\cancel{X_i},\cdots,\cancel{X_k},\cdots,X_{n_1+n_2+1})\right\}\\
&&
=dw_1\wedge w_2+(-1)^{\mathrm{deg} w_1}w_1\wedge dw_2
\end{eqnarray*}

I hope I'm not totally wrong and that makes some sense, also I didn't write the entire derivation, since I believe it would be too long and maybe tedious. Any guidance would be appreciated.